# Triggering a 404, 500, 503 error in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, http-request, response, http-header

Is there a standard way in Magento 2 to programmatically trigger an HTTP error state and have the system just deal with it?  i.e. is there a standard exception we can throw or global method we can call when, in our code, something unexpected happens and we just want to send the user to an error page?

Or is the only way to deal with this to create your own error state, and then ensure your controller's `execute` method returns an appropriate error code?

Answer (score 7):

You can always return `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw` with custom status header.

Also you can send 404 by throwing `\Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException`. It will be processed in `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php:61` to 'noroute' path, which will resolve to `\Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index` (or more specific if defined) that will set 404 header.

Most non-init errors will resolve to 503 Response code. See `\Magento\Framework\App\Http::catchException` for details.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Anton Kril, this worked for me.

```
namespace Company\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    public function execute() {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Some Exception message.'));                 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to show 404 error page.

```
namespace Company\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
{

    /**
     * Show 404 error page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward $resultForward */
        $resultForward = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_FORWARD);
        $resultForward->forward('noroute');
        return $resultForward;
    }

}
```